# Reload current route in emberjs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js

I currently have a controller that does some asynchronous loading of a list of data. 
In several other controllers I have functions that observe when this loading is finished and reload some models.

Small setup of my project:

```
App.SyncController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  finished: false,

  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('/data', function(data) {
      // Process data
      self.set('finished', true);
    });
  }
});

App.OverviewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['sync'],

  finishedSyncingObserver: function() {
    // Reload or update some data in this controller
  }).observes('controllers.sync.finished')
});

App.DetailController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['sync'],

  finishedSyncingObserver: function() {
    // Reload or update some data in this controller
  }).observes('controllers.sync.finished')
});
```

In this example both the observers are being called when the jQuery get finishes. However, is it possible to see which controller is active so only one observer is executed?

Thanks

Comment: Your description is hard to understand. Maybe show some simple code with the controller and 2 others that observer this controllers loading?

Comment: It was indeed a bit confusing. Added a code example.

Comment: I think that make the ajax call in the init is not a good idea. Can you show your routes?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior, good hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have to admit that @Marcio is right in his comment, because the `init` function of a controller is only invoked once, but not knowing you exact use case it will be maybe ok, therefore here are two kind of naive approaches.

**What about using two different boolean's, and observe these**

```
App.SyncController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  finishedOverview: false,
  finishedDetail: false,

  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('/data', function(data) {
      // Process data
      if(thereIsDataForDetail) {
        self.set('finishedDetail', true);
      }
      if(thereIsDataForOverview) {
        self.set('finishedOverview', true);
      }
    });
  }
});

App.OverviewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['sync'],

  finishedSyncingObserver: function() {
    // Reload or update some data in this controller
  }).observes('controllers.sync.finishedOverview')
});

App.DetailController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['sync'],

  finishedSyncingObserver: function() {
    // Reload or update some data in this controller
  }).observes('controllers.sync.finishedDetail')
});
```

**Or the other way around without endeavouring observer**

```
App.SyncController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['overview', 'detail'],

  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('/data', function(data) {
      // Process data
      if(thereIsDataForDetail) {
        self.get('controllers.detail').send('setNewData', data);
      }
      if(thereIsDataForOverview) {
        self.get('controllers.overview').send('setNewData', data);
      }
    });
  }
});

App.OverviewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  setNewData: function(data) {
    // Reload or update some data in this controller
  })
});

App.DetailController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  setNewData: function(data) {
    // Reload or update some data in this controller
  })
});
```

Of course this simple approaches would not scale well if you had more then two controllers that rely on the `sync` controller.

### Edit in response to your last comment

If you need the current route at any point in time here is how you could do it:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  currentPath: ''
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathChanged: function() {
    App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

Then from inside your ajax callback you can do this to get the current route:

```
App.get('currentPath');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example. However the data I receive is a list of settings specific to that user. For example, should ID's be displayed in a list etc. When these settings are loaded the current view should be rerendered to show these values. 

I do not know in which view (or controller) the user is at the time the $.get completes. It would be nice if there was some sort of function to retrieve the current controller or route so I can access it and force a reload of data (which I now do with the observer).

Comment: @KevinJannis, edited my answer to include an example on how to get the current route at any point in time which seams what you really want, have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use the `App.get('currentPath')`to check in the function if it is the correct route with: `if (App.get('currentPath') == 'overview') { /* Do stuff */ }`. It seems to do the job! Thanks!